# retrieve image from access database using c#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am adding a image in binary format to ms access database with below code. Field data type in database where I store this image is `OLE Object`.

The value of reader["Photo"] is as below

```
(byte[])reader["Photo"] {byte[26]}  
byte[] [0]  83 byte [1] 0   byte [2] 121    
byte [3]    0   byte [4]    115 
byte [5]    0   byte [6]    116 
byte [7]    0   byte [8]    101 
byte [9]    0   byte [10]   109 
byte [11]   0   byte [12]   46  
byte [13]   0   byte [14]   66  
byte [15]   0   byte [16]   121 
byte [17]   0   byte [18]   116 
byte [19]   0   byte [20]   101 
byte [21]   0   byte [22]   91  
byte [23]   0   byte [24]   93  
byte [25]   0   byte

    private byte[] imageToByteArray()
    {
        //Store the profile image to the database in binary format
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        pbProfilePic.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        byte[] Pic_arr = new byte[ms.Length];
        ms.Position = 0;
        ms.Read(Pic_arr, 0, Pic_arr.Length);
        return Pic_arr;
    }
```

Now, I am retrieving this image from database with the help of below code.

```
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from Employees where EmpId=" + datarecordId + "", conn);
        OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        pbProfilePic.Image = byteArrayToImage((byte[])reader["Photo"]);


    public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
        Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
        return returnImage;
    }
```

But, I am receiving below error at `Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);`

Additional information: Parameter is not valid.

Can anyone will help me with this error.

Thanks.

I am using the below code to store image in binary format to MS access database

```
    private byte[] imageToByteArray()
    {
        //Store the profile image to the database in binary format
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        pbProfilePic.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        byte[] Pic_arr = new byte[ms.Length];
        ms.Position = 0;
        ms.Read(Pic_arr, 0, Pic_arr.Length);
        return Pic_arr;
    }
```

Comment: have you used the debugger..? what is the value of `reader["Photo"]` when you stop on that line..?

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140299/reading-image-from-access-parameter-not-valid

Comment: @MethodMan : The value of `reader["Photo"]` is as below

(byte[])reader["Photo"] {byte[26]} byte[]
  [0] 83 byte
  [1] 0 byte
  [2] 121 byte
  [3] 0 byte
  [4] 115 byte
  [5] 0 byte
  [6] 116 byte
  [7] 0 byte
  [8] 101 byte
  [9] 0 byte
  [10] 109 byte
  [11] 0 byte
  [12] 46 byte
  [13] 0 byte
  [14] 66 byte
  [15] 0 byte
  [16] 121 byte
  [17] 0 byte
  [18] 116 byte
  [19] 0 byte
  [20] 101 byte
  [21] 0 byte
  [22] 91 byte
  [23] 0 byte
  [24] 93 byte
  [25] 0 byte

Comment: The bytes you show form the UTF-16 encoded string "System.Byte[]"... Somewhere you're saving the wrong data to your database. Show the code where you save the image.

Comment: Hi `@CodeCaster`, I have updated my question with code where I am saving an image to ms access database

Answer (score 1):

You might try this:

```
    public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        Image retval = null;
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
        {
            retval = (Image)new Bitmap(stream);
        }
        return retval;
    }
```

Also, as methodMan said, what is the debugger telling you?  What is the value of byteArrayIn?  Was the MemoryStream properly initialized?

Comment: `MemoryStream` is initialized properly, but while reading the stream it is giving me an error "Parameter is not valid."

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error if I just create a byte[] from a random string of characters and use byteArrayToImage.  The problem is that your original Image data is bad.

I tried using your methods (imageToByteArray and byteArrayToImage) on a PictureBox with a jpg embedded as the image and it ran with no errors, both converting to a byte[] and then to an Image.  It sounds as if something may have corrupted the original data in your picture box.